# shelve does not sync to disk before close

Tags: python, shelve

After changing the version of python from 3.5 to 3.7, shelve does no longer write to disk when calling the sync method. However, when I use python 3.5 it does.

I also noticed the on python 3.7 a 'db' extension is appended to the shelve database file.

Does anybody know the reason for this and are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing the [python3.7-gdbm](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/python3.7-gdbm) package (It's an Ubuntu Xenial Server).

It can be installed with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-gdbm
```

After installing the gdbm package python will start storing the shelve as a GNU dbm instead of a Berkeley DB:

```
$ file *
shelve_obj_berkley:            Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)
shelve_obj_gdbm:               GNU dbm 1.x or ndbm database, little endian, old
```

Comment: Please accept your answer if it solved your problem (it worked for me).